# MS Access VBA modify existing hyperlink to a button that replaces part of the url

Tags: vba, ms-access

long time watcher, first time poster.

I am a bit of newbie with VBA and can't understand how to take an existing hyperlink (as text field) in MS Access and import the contents to a button that modifies a part of the URL.
E.g.
#1  https://salesforce.com/lightning/r/Account/123456/view
to
#2  https://salesforce.com/lightning/r/Account/123456/related/Assets/view

I know we can read fields as variables, I am just stuck on the modification part.
I want to build a button that takes the URL from #1 and replaces /view with /related/Assets/view.

I know there should be a variable:

W = URL - end characters

Else
Variable = W & "string/to/add"

I feel like I have A and D, just not the B&C.

Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks!

---

Update: I think I figured it out, but probably not the most efficient way.

Private Sub AssetLinkBtn_Click()

Dim AssetLink

AssetLink = Left(AccountLink, 70) & "related/Assets/view"

FollowHyperlink AssetLink

End Sub

Comment: What's the context? Where's the code showing what you are attempting to do with the hyperlink?

Comment: In query, textbox or VBA: `Replace([fieldname], "view", "related/Assets/view")`

Comment: A textbox can be made to look and act like a button.